# Git command doesn't work on Visual Studio Code

Tags: command, visual-studio-code

I have installed Git on my window laptop, it works when i use the window terminal but it doesn't work with the Visual Studio Code terminal.

Someone could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "it doesn't work with the Visual Studio Code terminal" what is the error?

Comment: In the windows terminal it works, i have the same problem with npm and node

Comment: "unknown command"

Comment: Given that npm and node do the same thing, this isn't a Git issue, it's a path issue (you haven't told VS how to find the various commands).

Answer (score 1):

First try reloading VSCode.
After that, try running `git --version` in your VSCode terminal, if it shows you an error that means you did some part of your installation wrong and you do not have git installed and you'll have to reinstalled again.

If you're saying that in the windows terminal works, you should only restart VSCode.

Comment: yes in the windows terminal it works, i have the same problem with npm and node

Comment: Have you restarted VS Code?